# Static method in C++ "Interface"

Tags: c++, interface, static

I have a C++ "Interface" class and get the following error when trying to compile:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "Serializable::writeString(std::ostream&, std::string)", referenced from:
          Person::writeObject(std::ostream&) in Person.o
          Artist::writeObject(std::ostream&) in Artist.o
      "Serializable::readString(std::istream&)", referenced from:
          Person::readObject(std::istream&) in Person.o
          Artist::readObject(std::istream&) in Artist.o
      ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Is it possible to implement a static method in an abstract class?**

My implementation looks like this.

**.h File**

```
#ifndef Ex04_Serializable_h
#define Ex04_Serializable_h

using namespace std;

class Serializable {

public:
    virtual void writeObject(ostream &out) = 0;
    virtual void readObject(istream &in) = 0;

    static void writeString(ostream &out, string str);
    static string readString(istream &in);
};

#endif
```

**.cpp File**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Serializable.h"

using namespace std;

static void writeString(ostream &out, string str) {

    int length = str.length();

    // write string length first
    out.write((char*) &length, sizeof(int));

    // write string itself
    out.write((char*) str.c_str(), length);
}

static string readString(istream &in) {

    int length;
    string s;

    // read string length first
    in.read((char*) &length, sizeof(int));
    s.resize(length);

    // read string itself
    in.read((char*) s.c_str(), length);
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try:

```
void Serializable::writeString (...) {
 // ...
}
```

(try it without the static, and add the class name)

Comment: Well, I tried that already... Since an abstract class can not be directly initialized, I really need a static classfunction here.

Comment: it will be static -- keep the static in the .h file but remove the static from the .cpp file  (static has different connotations in both locations, and it is sufficient to put it in the .h file, and incorrect to put it in the .cpp file)

Comment: How do you figure that you really need a static function here? Did you get some kind of error?  Or is it just your gut feeling?  Because "Static" in this context in C++ means "not visible for linking". It does not mean "non-instance" as it does in C# and Java. So, you are saying that the function is not linkable, and of course later on the linker cannot find it.

Comment: Oh I see. Compiles now... Awesome.